# Does sympy v1.0 factor give the wrong answer with (2*4) + (2*4)/(2 + x)?

Tags: python, sympy

Using python 3.5.1 64 bit on windows 8.1, I have installed sympy, 1.0.

Running interactively

```
from sympy import *
p = symbols('p')
factor('8 + 8/(2+p)')
```

result is `8*(p + 3)/(p + 2)`.

If I go to http://live.sympy.org/ running sympy 0.7.6 and python 2.7.5 and enter the same equation and hit the evaluate button, I get the right answer.

```
8 + 8/(2+p)
```

There is no reduction.  Why am I getting the wrong answer with Python 3.5.1 and sympy 1.0?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not getting the wrong answer. All that [`sympy.factor`](http://docs.sympy.org/dev/tutorial/simplification.html#factor) ensures is that a polynomial is factored into irreducible fractions over the rationals.

Notice that

[image]

So the form given by `factor` in version 1.0 is correct, and represents an irreducible fraction over the rationals.

**Update** : I ran your code on SymPy Live and you get the exact same fraction when using `factor`, without the 8 factored out. They are the same. Note as Steven Rumbalski said, that *evaluating* and *factoring* are two different things.

Answer (score 1):

Using the link to http://live.sympy.org/ you provided i entered:

```
>>> p = symbols('p')
... factor('8 + 8/(2+p)')
(8p+24)/(p+2)

>>> '8 + 8/(2+p)'
8+8/(2+p)
```

As you can see there is a difference between factoring an expression and evaluating it.  The SymPy 0.7.6 result `(8p+24)/(p+2)` is equivalent to the SymPy 1.0 result you provided `8*(p + 3)/(p + 2)` except `8` has been pulled out as a separate factor in SymPy 1.0.

Comment: Ahh, sorry I didn't see this when I was updating my answer.

Comment: Yeah, I don't know anything about SymPy, but I can use an interactive interpreter and do basic maths.  :)  I upvoted your answer because you know your stuff.